# Is possible to hide scrollbar on mobile for webpage?

Tags: html, css, mobile, scrollbar

I'm trying hide scrollbar on mobile. Everything looks well on desktop (no srollbar), but when I check on some android device (ipad) - I can still see grey, thin thumb. Is possible to hide predefined scrollbar from browser.

My code (work well on desktop).

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: is it horizontal or vertical?

Comment: visibility:hidden  try this in thumb

Answer (score 6):

This was useful for me.

`::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Comment: Useful to know, you can target the directions independently with `::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal{}` and `::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical{}`. In my case I wanted to preserve horizontal ones.

Answer (score 3):

try this hide's it on screens less than `768px`

```css
body{
  height: 1000vh
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Yao</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `-webkit-appearance:none` to hide the scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
```

Comment: `width: 0` would be enough. But works, thanks :-)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It worked on desktop but not on mobile.

Answer (score -1):

None of the previous answers worked for me. I had to add:

```
main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then on mobile view through the browser there was no scroll bar to the right, but the scroll functionality still works.

Comment: scrolling is disabled if using this