# Scrollbar isn't hidden on mobile

Tags: html, css, vue.js, mobile, scroll

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar from every element on my Vue + Vite app. I don't want to disable scroll, just hide it, so I'm using the following code.

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

It works fine and the scrollbar is hidden on desktop dimensions, but it doesn't disappear on mobile, even on Chrome devtools mobile. Here's my meta if that's of any help.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I'm using a default Vue Vite app, with some vertically overflowing content.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to make the scrollbar transparent:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
background: transparent; 
}
```

You should place this code on a @media tag, so that it only affects mobile.

This solution was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284960/is-possible-to-hide-scrollbar-on-mobile-for-webpage) thread.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, when I enable the mobile view on Chrome, it still shows the scrollbar when scrolling